# segfault when accessing nested structure

Tags: c, struct, segmentation-fault, freebsd

I'm using `kinfo_getproc` in the following:

```
int main() {

    struct kinfo_proc *kp;

    kp = kinfo_getproc(getpid());


    printf("kp: %p\n", kp);
    // kp:  0x801216000

    printf("&kp: %p\n", &kp);
    // &kp: 0x7fffffffeac0

    printf("&thread: %p\n", &kp->ki_tdaddr);
    // &thread: 0x801216398


    printf("&thread->td_dupfd: %p\n", &kp->ki_tdaddr->td_dupfd);
    // &thread->td_dupfd: 0xfffff801564d3650

    // segfault accessing contents of td_dupfd
    //printf("thread->td_dupfd: %d\n", kp->ki_tdaddr->td_dupfd);

    return 1;
}
```

When I attempt to access a structure within the `kp` structure, the program segfaults.

I read, from other posts, the issue is likely that the structure is not allocated properly?
The following is from the man page for `kinfo_getproc`:

```
RETURN VALUES
   On success the kinfo_getproc() function returns a pointer to a struct
   kinfo_proc structure as defined by <sys/user.h>.  The pointer was
   obtained by an internal call to malloc(3) and must be freed by the caller
   with a call to free(3).  On failure the kinfo_getproc() function returns
   NULL.
```

If the return value is a pointer to a `kinfo_struct` that's already been `malloc`ed, shouldn't
accessing a nested structure just work? How should I properly access a nested structure in `kp`?

Comment: Don't comment out the code that has the problem you're asking about.

Comment: What's the value of `kp->ki_tdaddr`? Maybe it's a null pointer?

Comment: The documentation your posting makes no claims about whether the member `ki_tdaddr` is valid, nor whether what it possibly points to was `malloc`ed. It refers specifically to the resulting pointer from the `kinfo_getproc` only. You'll have to dive deeper to see when/if/how the `ki_tdaddr` member is handled.

Comment: A proc is not a thread, why do you expect this member to be valid? It will only be valid if you are calling this from a created thread.

Comment: Segfault does not occur because of accessing a nested struct it happens because of accessing a memory location which does not belong you or your Program.

Comment: @WhozCraig, dug deeper and it became obvious, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out what my problem was.

The value of `kp->ki_tdaddr` is an address that resides in kernel space. In other words, `kp->ki_tdaddr` is a pointer to a structure that lives in kernel memory - which is not directly accessible from userspace, hence the segfault.

The thing to do was use the value found in `kp->ki_tdaddr` (a kernel space address) with `kvm_read()` to transfer the bits from kernel space to user space.

code:

```
int main() {

    struct thread thread;

    /* a structure with process related info */
    struct kinfo_proc *kp = kinfo_getproc(getpid());

    /* a descriptor to access kernel virtual memory */
    kvm_t *kd = kvm_open(NULL, NULL, NULL, O_RDONLY, NULL);

    /* transfer bytes from ki_tdaddr to thread */
    kvm_read(kd, (unsigned long) kp->ki_tdaddr, &thread, sizeof(thread));

    /* can now access thread information */
    printf("thread id: %jd\n", (intmax_t) thread.td_tid);

    return 1;
}
```